# CROS error in asp.net core3.1 and signalr Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

i followed the exact tutorial from

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

and then i wanted to access the hub from another Origin. so i followed the exact instructions in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-3.1

but i get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:55039/myhub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'http://localhost:54114' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

here is the code:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddCors();
 services.AddSignalR(o =>
            {
                o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                o.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            });
}
```

and :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {   
app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:54114/")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                    .AllowCredentials();
            });
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/myhub");
            });
}
```

asp.net core 3.1

AspNetCore.SignalR

any tips and guides will be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Configure the CORS like below:

*ConfigureServices*

```
services.AddCors(options => 
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:44338")
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                   .AllowCredentials();
        }));
        services.AddSignalR(o =>
        {
            o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            o.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        });
```

*Configure*

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
       //...
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        //...

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Cors middleware should be called just before routing middleware.